# How to get URL of admin controller method in Magento?

Tags: magento-1.8

I have the following file structure:

> community/Sandipan
>
> community/Sandipan/controllers/Adminhtml/ProductfileuploadbackendController.php
> [1]

I have a template file in the following directory:

> design/adminhtml/default/default/template/productfileupload/catalog/product/tab.phtml [2]

My class [1] looks like this:

```
class Sandipan_Productfileupload_Adminhtml_ProductfileuploadbackendController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action {
    
    public method deleteRecordAction() {
    
    }

}
```

I want to send AJAX request to `deleteRecordAction` from my template [2], how can I do that? I tried the following:

```
Mage::helper("adminhtml")>getUrl("adminhtml/productfileuploadbackend/deleteRecord");
```

But it's not working.

Comment: can you please add config.xml code in question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If  your module `config.xml` configure  is `properly` and configure like

```
<config>
....
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <Sandipan_Productfileupload before="Mage_Adminhtml">Sandipan_Productfileupload_Adminhtml</Sandipan_Productfileupload>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
....    
</config>
```

**Then**

```
Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl('adminhtml/productfileuploadbackend/deleteRecord', ['_secure' => true]);
```

should work properly

Comment: Here's what my config.xml looks like, but it doesn't work. http://pastebin.com/LiimsVKL

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in function. You should replace the `method` with `function`.

Please see the attached screenshot
[image]